# In Django, how to raise non-validation errors during Model.save()?

Tags: python, django

I'm facing a strange use case, and I'm not sure how to proceed.

I'm overriding the `save()` method on a `DNSRecord Model`. The main reason for the override is to add extra side effects for additional work that must be done on external systems as part of the save. The additional operations include:

1. Fecthing an empty instance of IPAddress from the IPAddress model table,
2. Updating said IPAddress, and
3. Making a sequence of REST API calls to actually create the DNS records in UltraDNS.

Besides the write to `DNSRecord`, each of these three side effects can end up failing, at which point the save should be aborted (for atomicity) and reported to the user.

I have transaction safety down, but I'm unsure how to report the error back to the user in a way that makes sense. I have read that `ValidationErrors` are not the proper thing to use here, and some sources say it's ideal not to `raise` any exceptions in `save()` at all, which seems far too strict. How should I handle these cases in a way that both allows me to provide feedback as to why the error occurred while still failing gracefully?

As a heads up, I am using only the the admin interface.

Comment: You don't need to raise any exception, you just make sure that all  went well and return True or False if not, then in the view you can check how the `form.save()` went and show a message to the user to tell him that the form is valid but the save went wrong ...

Answer (score 1):

I usually keep this checks inside an atomic block and then raise the exception, see if you can get anything from it -

In the model -

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk is None:
        ....

    if self.date_created is None:
        .....

    with transaction.atomic():
        self.clean()  # my personal clean method
        raise Exception("This is a dummy exception") #this will automatically roll back all the save methods call hierarchy if they are also following this process, to nothing is saved
        super().save()
```

In the view class (Class based view) to show the user the error message -

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    if form.is_valid():
        .......  # create the model
        try:
             model.save()
             return self.form_valid(form)
        except Exception as err:
             messages.error(request, str(err))
    return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Then in the template show them as  -

```
<div class="flash_message hide">
                        {% if messages %}
                        <ul class="messages">
                            {% for message in messages %}
                            <li{% if message.tags %} class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>
                            {{ message|safe }}
                            </li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
```

Note: I used the [Django Message Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/) for passing the messages from view to templates. I also use twitter bootstrap 3, so my templates are formatted like so.

You can also subclass `Exception` to add custom errors.